# Get current row number PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database and query which returns 10 results. I want to print the total number of rows and the number of each column. 
What I've got so far is:

```
if($statement->rowCount())
{


    while ($entry = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


        print $statement->rowCount();
        print "<br />";
```

What is missing in this code is the current row number, which I don't know how to get.
The current result is 10 times 10, what I want is 10 1, 10 2 .....

Comment: So you want the value of a column that you created and selected to be handled for you by PDO via some magic method? That's not how it works I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to keep a counter variable, like below:

```
$row_count = 0;
if ($statement->rowCount())
{
    while ($entry = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Do useful stuff here, like print the row count
        $row_count++;
    }
}
```

You can also do `var_dump($entry)` to see if that one contains any useful count variables (I haven't checked whether there are, since I would just go for the counter variable.)